# Access VBA to open webpage with SSO requirement

Tags: vba, ms-access, single-sign-on, html

I am trying to use a button click to open a webpage on a secure SharePoint site, using SSO (single sign-on).  This works in Excel with the hyperlink set as a property to a shape and no VBA or macro (automatically runs Microsoft sign-on dialog box), but not in Access.  I receive the error "Unable to open https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx. Cannot download the information you requested."  Or I get a "Run-time Error '8' Cannot download the information you requested."

If I set the hyperlink in the button properties Hyperlink area, I can open the dialog box, click "bookmark", receive the message that the document has no bookmarks, and then the hyperlink works.  It will not work through VBA, and I don't want to manipulate through the bookmarks error to get the hyperlinks property dialog to work.

My generic code is:

```
Private Sub Cmd_ZD_Homepage_Click()

  Application.FollowHyperlink "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx"

End Sub
```

What do I need to add to the VBA code to work through the SSO portion of the webpage?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html

Comment: I copied/pasted the module and then inserted this code into my VBA:`Private Sub Cmd_ZD_Homepage_Click()

  Call PrepHyperlink("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx")
  
      strAddress = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx"
  
  Call GoHyperlink("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx")
  
End Sub`  I still receive the same error.  I am not familiar with public functions, so I assume I am calling it incorrectly in my code for the button click?

Comment: You would call the function `GoHyperlink`. That function calls `PrepHyperlink`, you don't.

Comment: It is possible this code will not resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues with FollowHyperlink so used Windows Shell to run:

```
Private Sub btnLink_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrProc
'FollowHyperlink is not working properly
''Application.FollowHyperlink Me.tbxLink
Dim wsShell As Object
Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsShell.Run Chr(34) & Me.tbxLink & Chr(34)
Me.Title.SetFocus
ExitProc:
Set wsShell = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrProc:
MsgBox "Cannot open document. Contact database administrator. : " & Err.Number
End Sub
```

However, I was just opening PDF files, not a web page associated with SharePoint.

Comment: I modified the code slightly, and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!  Modified code for my form is: `Private Sub Cmd_ZD_Homepage_Click()

  On Error GoTo ErrProc

  Dim wsShell As Object
  Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  wsShell.Run Chr(34) & "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Lean%20Home.aspx" & Chr(34)

ExitProc:
  Set wsShell = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrProc:
  MsgBox "Cannot open document. Contact database administrator. : " & Err.Number

End Sub`